# How to attach files to an email sent by a WordPress booking plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I'm using a WordPress plugin for accepting online bookings (Appointment Hour Booking) and I need to attach a file to the emails sent after submitting the booking request (a PDF file with the general booking terms). I already applied a solution by editing the calls to the wp_mail() function in this way:

```
wp_mail(trim($payer_email), $subject, $message, 
         "From: ".$from."\r\n". 
          $content_type. "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(), 
          array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/agreement.pdf'));
```

The above works but everytime the plugin updates the file is overwritten and I've to reapply the code modification again. There is a better way to do that without being affected by the plugin updates or there is a way to prevent partially or completely a plugin update in WordPress?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the plugin update isn't a good idea, you may lost important compatibility or security updates. The way the call to the wp_mail() was modified also causes other attachment-related features stop working. The plugin you mention has a filter that can be used to modify the list of attached files, you can put the following code for example into your theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'cpappb_email_attachments', 'my_attach_function', 10, 3 );

function my_attach_function( $attachments, $params, $form_id )
{
   $attachments[] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/agreement.pdf';
   return $attachments; 
}
```

With the above code located out of the plugin files your file is added to the list of attachments without removing other attachments and locating the code out of the plugin files will prevent being overwritten by the plugin updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- Fork the plugin and customize it to your needs.
- Ask the team behind the plugin to implement a filter hook to allow customizing the headers passed to the wp_mail() function (so you can then attach files to e-mails).
- Keep doing what you have been doing until now.

I like option two the best because:

1. It allows you to customize the behavior of the plugin from the outside, and,
2. Your changes will survive plugin updates.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Got a solution with a filter hook as recommended.